# I want to make a procedurally generated virtualized drive - how can I do this?

Tags: storage, virtualization

I've had the idea for a procedurally generated virtual drive bouncing around my head for a long time. It wouldn't really have any uses, and really it would just be for the memes, but I've finally settled down and decided to make it.

The idea is to make a fake drive that, whenever a program asks for a sector from, a bit of code will generate that sector on the fly (instead of reading it from a storage medium like a normal drive). Of course, writing to the disk would be impossible, but that's ok - I'm just doing this for fun.

**Question is: how do I actually make this appear as a drive?**

I should think there's a library out there *somewhere* that will let you directly, but I haven't been able to find it yet. I don't really know what keywords I should be searching for, either.

I have a lot of experience with Arduinos and hardware - would it be easier to simply connect the SPI pins to an SD card slot and get the *Arduino* to generate the "sectors"?

I'm thinking of using this to play around with file systems and ridiculously large files - after all, there is no limit to how big the drive can be (since it doesn't require any real memory), besides 32 bit or 64 bit limits, which could be a lot of fun - if only to pretend you have a zettabyte of disk space. Even though it would be read only, I'm curious how Notepad would handle a petabyte txt file.

If anyone has any ideas on how to do this, or knows some better keywords I can use to search for this, let me know!

(I am *fairly* fluent in Python, Arduino, and I can do a little C if I sit down with a coffee)

Comment: A virtual *drive* (something addressable at the sector level) is either uncommon, or just immediate, because in a Unix like OS the `seek` function allows to create a [sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file). You can pretend having a file the size of which is only limited per the 64 bits addresses, provided it mainly contains empty segments of null bytes. If you want a virtual filesystem (possibility of creating files there) then you have memory file systems implementation on Linux, or if using Python the excellent [pyfakefs](https://pypi.org/project/pyfakefs/) module.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify how you wanted to tackle this, but on Linux there's [Fuse](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/fuse.html), the **F**ilesystem in **Use**rspace. It's a library that allows you to implement functions that handle the usual filestem operations, i.e. enumerating files and directories, opening files and reading/writing to them.

It also has a [python wrapper](https://pypi.org/project/fuse-python/) and a [tutorial](https://thepythoncorner.com/posts/2017-02-28-writing-a-fuse-filesystem-in-python/).